# ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY date_column)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005-express

I am wondering. I have a complex query which runs in a SQL Server 2005 Express edition in around 3 seconds.

The main table has around 300k rows.

When I add

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_column)
```

it takes 123 seconds while `date_column` is a `datetime` column.

If I do

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY string_title)
```

it runs in 3 seconds again.

I added an index on the `datetime` column. No change. Still 123 seconds.

Then I tried:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(date_column AS int))
```

and the query runs in 3 seconds again.

Since casting needs time, why does SQL Server behave like this???

UPDATE:
It seems like ROW_NUMBER ignore my WHERE statements at all and build a row column list for all available entries? Can anyone confirm that ?

Here I copied a better read able (still tonz of logic :)) in the SQL Management Studio:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xinfobase.lid) AS row_num, *
FROM xinfobase
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xinfobasetree] ON [xinfobasetree].[lid] = [xinfobase].[xlngfolder] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xapptqadr] ON [xapptqadr].[lid] = [xinfobase].[xlngcontact] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [xinfobasepvaluesdyn] ON [xinfobasepvaluesdyn].[lparentid] = [xinfobase].[lid] 
WHERE (xinfobase.xlngisdeleted=2 
AND xinfobase.xlinvalid=2) 
AND (xinfobase.xlngcurrent=1) 
AND ( (xinfobase.lownerid = 1  
       OR (SELECT COUNT(lid) 
           FROM xinfobaseacl 
           WHERE xinfobaseacl.lparentid = xinfobase.lid 
             AND xlactor IN(1,-3,-4,-230,-243,-254,-255,-256,-257,-268,-589,-5,-6,-7,-8,-675,-676,-677,-9,-10,-864,-661,-671,-913))>0 
               OR xinfobasetree.xlresponsible = 1) 
AND (xinfobase.lid IN (SELECT lparentid 
                       FROM xinfobasealt a, xinfobasetree t 
                       WHERE a.xlfolder IN(1369) 
                         AND a.xlfolder = t.lid 
                         AND dbo.sf_MatchRights(1, t.xtxtrights,'|')=1 )) ) 
AND ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.fn_Split(cf_17,',') 
      WHERE [value] = 39)>0)
```

This query need 2-3 seconds on 300k records.
Now I changed the `ORDER BY` to `xinfobase.xstrtitle` then it runs in around 2-3 seconds again.
If I switch to `xinfobase.dtedit` (datetime column with an additional index I just added) it needs hte time I mentioned above already.

I also tried to "cheat" and made my statement as a SUB SELECT to force him to retriev the records first and do a `ROW_NUMBER()` outside in another SQL statement, same performance result.

Comment: Not that much time; other things (like a table scan when one shouldn't be needed) can far exceed the overhead of a cast.

Comment: +1 for the performance questioning :)

Comment: I checked my indexes and they are fine regarding my where statements.

Comment: Show your entire query, and the results of your estimated query plan from SSMS.

Comment: Btw, the sql statement is created by Ruby on Rails in the ORM mapping, so I checked my log files and fetched the created SQL statement. The gem "will paginate" is used here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can post the SQL but since it is created by RoR it is not really nice to read :)

Comment: You may need to run a custom query or stored procedure, instead of the RoR generated one.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716798/sql-server-2008-ordering-by-datetime-is-too-slow). Same question, several good answers.

Comment: @jpw I checked the indexes so far. and as you can see in my post, I tested with string_column which is not even in the index and my query runs in 3 seconds.

Comment: You may also want to have a look here if you want to page the result set: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml (`SET ROWCOUNT`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Interesting article but in my case rails created the stuff using active record, so not much of a choice. My workaround is to cast it as an int and put the datetime column in another column, but I wonder why I have todo this...

Comment: Compare the plans with date column and integer column side by side and see what is the main diff. Did you update the stats on the tables involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After I was still frustrated about doing a workaround I was investigating more.
I removed all my existing indexes and run several SQL statements against the tables.
It turns out, that building new indexes with a new sortorder of columns and include different columns I fixed my issue and the query is fast with dtedit (datetime) column as well.

So lessons learned:
Take more care of your indexes and execution plans and recheck them with every update (new version) of the software you produce...

But still wonderung why CAST(datetime_column AS int) makes it fast before...